# Retrieve json data from array using select

Tags: php, mysql, json

Lets say I have this info stored in my database, in a JSON format.

```
ROW with id=23: {
    "age":50,
    "name":"Nick",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
}

ROW with id=24: {
    "age":22,
    "name":"John",
    "messages":["msg 4","msg 3","msg 9"]
}
```

Now, all I want is to perform an SQL query using PHP to retrieve rows that contains the message `msg 3`.

How can I do that?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `where col like '%msg 3%'`

Comment: This does not seem like a good schema approach.  Using the WHERE clause pointed out by `@AbhikChakraborty above, you will NEVER be able to use an index when performing this lookup.  Make sure you have the ability to perform a lookup where you can leverage an index.

Comment: I also need to know that "msg 3" is contained in the "messages" variable, not in "age" variable for example

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a NoSQL storage with the way you are wanting to work with this data structure.

Comment: You really should just move any fields that you need to query on out of the json into their own column. This will make you life much easier. You can use indexes and more.

Comment: @vzamanillo . I use MySQL

Comment: Up to 5.7 MySQL implements a couple of SQL functions to manipulate JSON, take a look at http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=516202 and http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/, the problem... performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE '%%' is performance overkill, try to avoid that.
Objects are made to live, why fossilize them ?
Not to mention, this is also obviously violating 1NF.

As someone suggested, why don't you try MongoDB or other NoSQL database ? Queries are performed using JSON (well, BSON...)